# How to set selected item of a ComboBox to another value?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently trying to set my selected item in a Combobox to a different value. In this example I am using shoe sizes, I want to select a shoe size and upon selecting a shoe size and hitting the start button i want it to read the size code.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/ItnSq]

This is what I have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboBoxDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  //declarations
  JButton btnPay = new JButton("Start");

  /*ShoeSizeArray 
  String[] comboLabels = {"5", "5.5","6", "6.5", "7", "7.5", "8", "8.5", "9", "9.5", "10", "10.5", "11", "11.5", 
  "12.5", "13.5", "14", "14.5", "15.5", "16"};*/

  //Sizecode Array
  String[] comboLabels = {"560", "570", "580", "590", "600", "610", "620", "630", "640", "650", "660", "670", "680", "690", "700", "710",
    "720", "730", "740", "750", "760", "770"};
  JComboBox <String> combo = new JComboBox<String>(comboLabels);
  JTextArea display = new JTextArea(5,20); 

  //constructor
  public ComboBoxDemo(){
    super("Combo box");
    //panel for button and combobox
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    //add panel to frame
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //add button and combobox to panel
    buttonPanel.add(btnPay);
    buttonPanel.add(combo);
    //register button with ActionListener
    btnPay.addActionListener(this);
    //add text area to center of frame
    add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String sizecode = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
    display.append("\nYou selected the sizecode " + sizecode);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame fr = new ComboBoxDemo();
    fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    fr.setSize(200,200);
    fr.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What issue do you face?

Comment: at the moment I have no clue on how to set my selected index value from the ComboBox to another value. this is what I am currently stuck with.

http://i.imgur.com/nwn3FS0.png

Comment: I am still not getting what you are trying to achieve. When you are click on start it is displaying the selected combobox value. Now what you want to change?

Comment: @Beniton what I want to do is, when i select the shoe size 5 and click on the start button i want it to display the size code 560. basically when selecting 5 it should display 560. this is what i currently have  i.imgur.com/nwn3FS0.png

Comment: Ok i got it. Create and shoe data model and then you can achieve it.

Comment: @Beniton so would i create a seperate shoe class, and then store those values in an array? and then create the models like so?

private ArrayList<Shoe> shoes = new ArrayList<Shoe>();
DefaultListModel<Shoe> shoeModel = new DefaultListModel<Shoe>();

Comment: I have give the code in the answer. It should help you.

Comment: your codes/sizes don't match, you have 20 sizes and 22 codes - please provide how you map these values! (where is size 12, 13, 15? this would result in another mismatch)

Comment: `your codes/sizes don't match` - and this is a reason you should not be using two arrays. You should be using a custom object with two properties.

Answer (score 1):

You create a Shoesize class and setting the label based on the selection.

Below code should help you.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ComboBoxDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // declarations
    JButton btnPay = new JButton("Start");

    // ShoeSizeArray
    String[] sizes = { "5", "5.5", "6", "6.5", "7", "7.5", "8", "8.5", "9", "9.5", "10", "10.5", "11", "11.5", "12.5",
            "13.5", "14", "14.5", "15.5", "16" };

    // Sizecode Array
    String[] comboLabels = { "560", "570", "580", "590", "600", "610", "620", "630", "640", "650", "660", "670", "680",
            "690", "700", "710", "720", "730", "740", "750", "760", "770" };
    JComboBox<Shoesize> combo = new JComboBox<Shoesize>();
    JTextArea display = new JTextArea(5, 20);

    // constructor
    public ComboBoxDemo() {
        super("Combo box");
        // panel for button and combobox
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        // add panel to frame
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            Shoesize size = new Shoesize(Double.parseDouble(sizes[i]), comboLabels[i]);
            combo.addItem(size);
        }
        // add button and combobox to panel
        buttonPanel.add(btnPay);
        buttonPanel.add(combo);
        // register button with ActionListener
        btnPay.addActionListener(this);
        // add text area to center of frame
        add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Shoesize sizecode = (Shoesize) combo.getSelectedItem();
        display.append("\nYou selected the sizecode " + sizecode.label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new ComboBoxDemo();
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fr.setSize(200, 200);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Shoesize {
        double size;
        String label;

        public Shoesize(double size, String label) {
            super();
            this.size = size;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            long temp;
            temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(size);
            result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Shoesize other = (Shoesize) obj;
            if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
                return false;
            if (Double.doubleToLongBits(size) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.size))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private ComboBoxDemo getOuterType() {
            return ComboBoxDemo.this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(size);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this worked really well, however i need size; in the Shoesize class to be a String, simply changing the datatype to String in the variable declaration and the constructor is fine but however the code breaks at the hashcode().

How can I change the size variable to be a String without breaking the code.

I know you're probably wondering why i would want the size variable to be a string, it is because i am later passing this into a toString method.

Comment: Please disregard my top message, everything is in working order, made a silly mistake. Thank you so much for your help Beniton!

Comment: @Mxxm, Don't use multiple arrays to store the data. If the data is related then it should be stored in a custom object that contains both properties. Then you add this object to the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply access the index from the box and navigate then through your arrays.

```
String[] shoeSizes = {"5",   "5.5", "6",   "6.5", "7",   "7.5", "8",   "8.5", "9",   "9.5", "10",  "10.5","11",  "11.5", "12.5", "13.5", "14", "14.5", "15.5", "16"};
String[] shoeCodes = {"560", "570", "580", "590", "600", "610", "620", "630", "640", "650", "660", "670", "680", "690",  "700",  "710",  "720", "730", "740",  "750", "760", "770"};

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    //access on the index not the object
    int selectedIndex = combo.getSelectedIndex();

    //use the index to get values for size/code
    String size = shoeSizes[selectedIndex];
    String code = shoeCodes [selectedIndex];

    //bring to front
    display.append("\nYou selected "+size"+, code is " + code );
}
```

this only works if you your arrays have the same length (`assert shoeSizes.length == shoeCodes.length;`)

Comment: Don't use multiple arrays to store the data. If the data is related then it should be stored in a custom object that contains both properties. Then you add this object to the combo box.

Comment: point taken: depends on your application - if you need your class in any other situation then you are right. if you only need within this context then creating a class rather bloats the code (my code changes three lines and one commentary line - can't be more clean for a beginner)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom object with multiple properties, (size, code). Add this object to the combo box and create a custom renderer to display the size property.

The code for a basic renderer would be something like:

```
class FooRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value instanceof Foo)
        {
            Foo foo = (Foo)value;
            setText( foo.getSize() );
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information and a more complete solution.